How to fix node-alignment and cell-spacing in table for Newton Interpolation Form in a simple/efficient way?
This is a repost of my original question since there was only 1 answer, and it was too advanced for me to understand/replicate. Here's a short recap and my MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix, tikz}

\begin{document}

\NiceMatrixOptions{cell-space-limits = 1mm}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{NiceArray}{c|c|c|c|c}
        x & p(x) & c_1 & c_2 & c_3 \\ \hline
        3 & 10 & & & \\
        & & \frac{146-10}{7-3} = 34 & & \\
        7 & 146 & & \frac{24-34}{1-3}= 5 & \\
        & & \frac{2-146}{1-7}=24 & & \frac{5-5}{2-3}=0 \\
        1 & 2 & & \frac{-1-24}{2-7}=5 & \\
        & & \frac{1-2}{2-1} = -1 & & \\
        2 & 1 & & &
        \CodeAfter
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=0.5mm] (2-1) -- (2-2);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >=1mm, shorten <=0.5mm] (4-1) -- (4-2);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >=2mm, shorten <=0.5mm] (6-1) -- (6-2);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >=2mm, shorten <=0.5mm] (8-1) -- (8-2);
            \tikz \draw[thick] (2-2) -- (3-3.north west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 1mm] (4-2.east) -- (3-3.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >=2mm] (4-2.east) -- (5-3.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 2mm] (6-2.east) -- (5-3.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >=2mm] (6-2.east) -- (7-3.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 2mm, shorten <= 1mm] (8-2.east) -- (7-3.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm] (3-3.east) -- (4-4.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm] (5-3.east) -- (4-4.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm] (5-3.east) -- (6-4.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm] (7-3.east) -- (6-4.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm] (4-4.east) -- (5-5.west);
            \tikz \draw[thick, shorten >= 1mm, shorten <= 1mm] (6-4.east) -- (5-5.west);
    \end{NiceArray}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}

The above was my original code for the task which results in the following output:

As you can see, the problem lies in me having to manually adjust the length of the nodes, and even then, it isn't consistently nor properly formatted. On top of that, the vertical spacing of the cell-distance in each column (c1-c3) is quite annoying to deal with as I have to create empty rows in order to manipulate the alignment to fit my needs. The original answer solved these issues (with the exception of 1 small issue which is that the horizontal line didn't extend all the way through for c3), but it was purely tikz at a level which I'm unable to comprehend. Solving my problem using nicematrix isn't a requirement, however. The important thing is a simple/efficient solution, and then it doesn't matter which packages/approaches are utilized to achieve this goal.
Note: If 1 solution already has been provided and you've figured out a different and just as efficient way to solve the problem, do not shy away from sharing since variety benefits us all, helping us to think in new and creative ways!:)
